# How to validate Column Names and Column Order in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want read the column names from a file stored in Azure Files And then validate the column names and sequence e.g. "First_Column"="First_Column", "Second_Column"= "Second_Column", ... etc and also the order should match. Please suggest a way to do this in Azure Data Factory.

Comment: I think you can validate it via [column patterns in derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern) in dataflow. `name` represents the name of each incoming column and `position` is the ordinal position of columns in your data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

1. Alternatively, we can use Lookup activity to view the headers, but the judgment condition will be a little complex.
   [image]
2. At the If Condition1 we can use the expression: `@and(and(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0,'First_Column'),equals(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_1,'Second_Column')),equals(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_2,'Third_Column'))`

[image]

---

We can validate the column names and sequence in dataflow via [column patterns in derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern).
For example:
The source data csv file is like this:
[image]

1. The dataflow is like this:
   [image]
   I don't select **First row as header** , so we can read the headers of the csv file into the dataflow.
   [image]
2. Then I use SurrogateKey1 to add a row_no to the data.
   [image]

The data preview is like this:
[image]

3. At ConditionalSplit1 activity, I use `row_no == 1` to filter the headers.
   [image]
4. At DerivedColumn1 activity, I use several column pattern to validate the column names and sequence.
   [image]
   The result is as follows:
   [image]

Comment: Thank you Joseph. Is it only possible through Dataflows. Without Dataflows is there any option in normal other activities in ADF?If possible.

Comment: Hi @Yogesh Kulkarni, I think we can use the Lookup activity and the If condition activity. But the judgment condition will be a little complex. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph. I will check this option.